# Windows Event Viewer ID for when certificate is installed

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, event-log, event-viewer

Is there any where in Windows Event Viewer that can show when a new certificate is installed on user or machine certificate stores?

All I found is this:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14250.certificate-services-lifecycle-notifications.aspx

these 2 specifically:

- CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System
- CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-User

and I tested it myself, Event Viewer logs new certificate installations only when the certificate has either the private key, is in `.pfx` format, or both.

so I created a dummy certificate with `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet, exported it without private keys in .cer format, deleted original cert that had private keys, then added the previously export cert to local machine certificate in trusted root store, Event Viewer didn't log it.

so how can I see any and all certificate changes in Event Viewer or using any other way?
almost always when a 3rd party program installs a certificate on the system or a bad actor installs a certificate, they are all without private keys.

how can I track those?